# Get multiple zipcode from each district latitude and longitude on Python

Tags: python, arcgis-online, geopandas, latitude-longitude, zip-codes

[image: Raw data]I am trying to create a column for Zipcode from Latitude and Longitude column.

I have seen multiple answers in StackExchange, all are for creating one zipcode from zipcode latitude and longitude. But mine is district latitude and longitude and what I want is to create a column get a zipcode from a district latitude and longitude and create rows for each zipcode while keeping the other column as it is.

For instance, if the first row of latitude and longitude has 3 zipcode, it will produce 3 rows for each zipcode while keeping other columns as it is. My code is below:

```
import geopandas as gpd
# Load your shapefile
gdf1 = gpd.read_file('Texas_State_House_Districts_88th_2023_2025.shp')

# Assuming 'geometry' column contains the shapes

# Function to convert the centroid or midpoint to (latitude, longitude)
def get_lat_lon(geom):
    if geom.geom_type == 'Polygon':
        point = geom.centroid
    elif geom.geom_type == 'LineString':
        point = geom.interpolate(0.5, normalized=True)
    return (point.y, point.x)

# Apply the function to your GeoDataFrame
gdf1['latitude'], gdf1['longitude'] = zip(*gdf1['geometry'].apply(get_lat_lon))

# Now, gdf contains two additional columns 'latitude' and 'longitude'

gdf1 = gdf1.drop(columns=['geometry'])

# Export to csv
gdf1.to_csv('data_State_House.csv', index=False)

gdf1.head()
```

[image]

Comment: @BERA added the data. Also you can find the data in this link https://gis-txdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/TXDOT::texas-state-house-districts/explore

Comment: Is there some logic to calculating zip codes? What is the problem with your code?